# Problems with buiding a query mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I've been add the some values to the `$_SESSION` array in this format `12,121,41`. Here my database for exampe:

```
|id|title|source
|1 |asda | 12
|2 |sadas| 121
```

And i need to build query to retrieve data from this table where source contains the values from my $_SESSION array.
Here var_dump of my $_SESSION var.

```
string(30) "12,121,41"
```

Some suggestions?
Sorry for my english, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sessionValues = $_SESSION['source'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE source IN ({$sessionValues})"
```

Answer (score 1):

for matching all session data with database field

```
$keyword = strreplace(",","','",$_SESSION);   
$query="select * from table where id in('$keyword')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

for particular session data

```
    $keyword =  $_SESSION;
    $query="select * from table where id =."$keyword[0]."; // as per your need you can change array key
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your query something like.

```
$query="select * from table where source in(".$_SESSION.")";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Answer (score -1):

connect to database and execute query as below:

```
$in  = $_SESSION['source'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE source IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($in_array);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Comment: No, session array has the automatically generated values. And i need to retrieve data with one query and don't manually.